# How to access data in dio response - _JsonMap

Tags: json, flutter, dio

I am making a request with dio

```
final Dio dio = new Dio();
return dio.post(api, data: data);
.then((response) {
  print(response.data.runtimeType);
  print(response.data);
  print(response.data.token);
}
```

The response data is printed, and the type is `_JsonMap`

When I want to print response.data.token I get this error

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'token'
```

How do I access the token value? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your syntax is right as according to the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#response-schema) the response format should be a `Response` object using which you can get the `data` and `headers`.

Not sure why it's `JsonMap` but you are accessing the response wrong since you have not deserialized it you should do this.

```
final Dio dio = new Dio();

return dio.post(api, data: data).then((response) {
  print(response.data.runtimeType);
  print(response.data);
  print(response.data['token']);
}
```

If such a key exists in the response, it'll print.